# Path with broken shadow effect

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, effects, shadow

I hope that it is clear enough in the image, I have a triangle with shadow effect that doesn't look so good, seems to be broken somehow.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(**Update:** the rectangle and the path have to be separated)

[image]

XAML:

```
    <Grid Height="50" Width="60" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="White">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="4" BlurRadius="10" />
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
        <Path Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,15,-1,15"
                        Data="M44.386378,164.8791 L22.983157,171.42119 44.713478,176.58567" Width="23.167">
            <Path.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="4" />
            </Path.Effect>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your triangle:

1. Remove the Margin
2. Set the Path height explicitly ("22" is pretty close what you have there).

That should prevent the triangle's shadow from being clipped.

Here's the xaml for that:

```
    <Grid Height="50" Width="60" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="White" >
        <Rectangle.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="4" BlurRadius="10" />
        </Rectangle.Effect>
    </Rectangle>
    <Path Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Data="M44.386378,164.8791 L22.983157,171.42119 44.713478,176.58567" Width="23.167" Height="22">
        <Path.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="4" />
        </Path.Effect>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have two separate elements each with a drop shadow. You cannot expect their shadows to join up nicely, the 'blur' is applied separately to each element. Try combining your rectangle and triangle into a single path. e.g.

```
<Path Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,15,-1,15"
        Data="M 0,0 L 100,0 L 100,400 L 0,400 L 0,300 L -50, 200 L 0, 100 L 0,0">
    <Path.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="4" />
    </Path.Effect>
</Path>
```

Comment: Sorry but I have to separate them since the box contains in the real situation data with dynamic with. and I don't want the data to influence on the triangle's width only on the rectangle's.