# Drop shadow effect in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, dropshadow

I'm looking for a way to add a `Drop Shadow Effect` to the multiple kind of elements in my Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime (not Silverlight!) application. The main problem is that.. there's no offical API for it. The main problem is that I need to mimic this effect not only to the basic shapes (like rectangle or a line), but also a path, like here:

[image: Taken from question /4519243/path-with-broken-shadow-effect]

Picture is borrowed from this question: [path-with-broken-shadow-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519243/path-with-broken-shadow-effect) - I hope the owner won't mind ;) Now, he has achieved this effect because it was done in WPF. I'm working on a Universal App (so WinRT), and there's no Effects extension.

I've searched the web multiple times, and found some kind of workarounds, but they all miss something. For example this one:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Simple-Xaml-Drop-Shadows-in-Silverlight-2.aspx <- I can't work on `Canvas`, the content has to be a `Grid`.

Do you any idea how can I achieve satisfying results on faking Drop Shadow Effect in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime?

Comment: The shown example would work in a `Grid` as well, or why can't you do it with a `Grid`?

Comment: Because for the moment I came up with a solution to use `Grid` as a root for the content (with transparent background), and then inside of the `Grid` I have placed `Path` that imitates that shape (I need almost the same shape, don't how to to call it). 
I don't know how could I mimic solution presented above to the `Path` object. And also, I don't use round shapes, and it looks much worse without it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apply a `RenderTransform` to the shadow shape. Set the scale to make it bigger:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}" Background="#FF803535" >             
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Opacity="0.3" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" StrokeThickness="16" StrokeDashCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" Stroke="Black"  >
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1.07" ScaleY="1.07"  />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Great idea! Thank you, it really does look better. I would've never come up with this on my own.

Ok, this is fine for simple elements, like `Border` or `Grid`. But what about `Path`? Should I just make 1 as main one (with background color), the rest transparent and just play with Stroke/Opacity/ScaleTransform values? 
The problem I'm now having is that my shape is not primitive (it's a rectangle with small triangle 'glued' at the bottom, very similiar to the shape in the topic).

EDIT: 
Ok, I see that you've set the RenderTransformOrigin. Sadly it's not enough for the shape I described above.

Comment: You have to duplicate the path, as shown in my example.